# Complex queries to find sum of rows depending on date

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE master_tb
(
    date DATE
    item VARCHAR(10)
    change INT
    current INT
);

INSERT INTO master_tb (date, item, change, current)
VALUES
    ("2021-01-01", "ABC", 11, 11),
    ("2021-01-01", "KLM", 4, 4),
    ("2021-01-02", "KLM", -3, 1),
    ("2021-01-03", "KLM", -1, 0),
    ("2021-02-01", "KLM", 6, 6),
    ("2021-02-02", "XYZ", 5, 5),
    ("2021-02-08", "KLM", -3, 3),
    ("2021-02-09", "XYZ", -1, 4),
    ("2021-03-02", "XYZ", 2, 6),
    ("2021-03-08", "XYZ", -1, 5),
    ("2021-03-08", "KLM", -3, 0);
```

I have the above table for an inventory log. I want to get 2 things:

1. The `current` value given a `@date`. So if my given date is 2021-03-09, even though that date doesn't exist in the list, it will give me the most recent values of all ABC, XYZ, and KLM items and their `current` status. So the select table would look something like this:

```
+------+---------+
| item | current |
+======+=========+
| ABC  | 11      |
+------+---------+
| XYZ  | 5       |
+------+---------+
| KLM  | 0       |
+------+---------+
```

2. Similarly, I want to get the current values but for specific timeframes, given a "now" date `@date` where that can be any date. So If `@date = 2021-4-1`, I am looking for something like this:

```
+------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
| item | total | 0-30 days | 31-60 days | 61-90 days | 90+ days |
+======+=======+===========+============+============+==========+
| XYZ  | 5     | 1         | 4          | 0          | 0        |
+------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
| ABC  | 11    | 0         | 0          | 11         | 0        |
+------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
| KLM  | 0     | 0         | 0          | 0          | 0        |
+------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

One thing to note is that "older" items are deducted if there was a deduction. So if 5x item XYZ was added 50 days ago, and 2x 20 days ago, and it was reduced 3x 10 days ago, the table would show `total = 4`, `0-30 days = 2`, and `31-60 days = 2` because the older items were deducted even tho the deduction occurred recently.

My first guess was to utilize partitions but I am not sure if that's possible, knowing the values outside of a partition is affected.

---

EDIT:
After a friend pointed out [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-last-value-from-any-table-in-sql-server/) I have found a way to answer the first part of the question:

```
SELECT
  item,
  MAX(curr) as current            // needed to group item columns
FROM(
  SELECT
    *, 
    LAST_VALUE(current) OVER      // partitioning was needed to
    (                             // find the most recent 'current'
      PARTITION BY item           // value added on that 'item'
      ORDER BY date
      RANGE BETWEEN
        UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
        UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) curr
  FROM tbl
  WHERE date <= @date
)a
WHERE bal = balance
GROUP BY item
;
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the hint, edited the question with a CREATE and INSERT query for reproductibility. I hope that helps

Comment: Can you solve *any* part of this problem?

Comment: @Strawberry Are you saying I should provide what I tried to do? I know my answer is wrong because it does not aggregate the right information. I simply do not know how to do so. I also figured my "answer" would just be additional clutter and distracting.

Comment: As per the linked answer to my original comment, knowing what you *can* do gives us some idea of where to start with our answer.

Comment: That said, I cannot see why the answer for '2021-04-01' would be any different from that for '2021-03-09'

Comment: @Strawberry They're two different questions. I'm going to assume you're asking for the 2nd question: 
Say date = '2021-04-01'. We would be looking at all data on or before that date. date = '2021-03-09' would be looking at less data. But that would also affect the partitions (30days-, 31-60days, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE master_tb
( date DATE
, item VARCHAR(10)
, change_x INT
, current INT
, PRIMARY KEY(date,item)
);

INSERT INTO master_tb (date, item, change_x, current)
VALUES
    ("2021-01-01", "ABC", 11, 11),
    ("2021-01-01", "KLM", 4, 4),
    ("2021-01-02", "KLM", -3, 1),
    ("2021-01-03", "KLM", -1, 0),
    ("2021-02-01", "KLM", 6, 6),
    ("2021-02-02", "XYZ", 5, 5),
    ("2021-02-08", "KLM", -3, 3),
    ("2021-02-09", "XYZ", -1, 4),
    ("2021-03-02", "XYZ", 2, 6),
    ("2021-03-08", "XYZ", -1, 5),
    ("2021-03-08", "KLM", -3, 0);
    
SELECT item
     , MAX(date) date 
  FROM master_tb 
 WHERE date <= '2021-03-09' 
 GROUP 
    BY item;
+------+------------+
| item | date       |
+------+------------+
| ABC  | 2021-01-01 |
| KLM  | 2021-03-08 |
| XYZ  | 2021-03-08 |
+------+------------+

SELECT a.*
  FROM master_tb a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT item
            , MAX(date) date 
         FROM master_tb 
        WHERE date <= '2021-03-09' 
        GROUP 
           BY item
     ) b
    ON b.item = a.item
   AND b.date = a.date;
   
+------------+------+----------+---------+
| date       | item | change_x | current |
+------------+------+----------+---------+
| 2021-01-01 | ABC  |       11 |      11 |
| 2021-03-08 | KLM  |       -3 |       0 |
| 2021-03-08 | XYZ  |       -1 |       5 |
+------------+------+----------+---------+
```

We could also solve this using common table expressions/windowing functions, and that might be useful when we come to look at the next part of the problem - although I have a suspicion that much of that should be resolved in application code.